# How to get XML from MYSQL using Python Flask?

Tags: mysql, xml, python-3.x, flask

I got a MYSQL database and a table in it. I want to convert this table into XML and be able to access the data in it using GET method, but the problem I am facing is, I want to know is it possible to use the Python Flask for this process to convert the table to an XML and store it in the memory (like JSON), can someone help me to give an idea of how to achieve this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get your [results as a dictionary](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor-class.html). Then apply [dicttoxml](https://pypi.org/project/dicttoxml/) to it, as in the following example:

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
import dicttoxml

conn = MySQLdb.Connect(
    host='localhost', user='user',
    passwd='secret', db='test')
cursor = conn.cursor(cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute("SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml({'results': rows}, attr_type=False)
```

Hope that helps...